# Falta tradução nas mensagens automáticas das análises

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução

Quando estava a fazer [esta análise](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/479), votei para fechar com a razão "esta é uma resposta só com link". À semelhança dos outros sites SE isto dispara um comentário automático na resposta, só que neste caso a mensagem não está traduzida.

Mensagem original:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Sugestão de tradução:

> Embora este *link* possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o *link* somente para referência. Respostas apenas com *link* podem se tornar inválidas se houver mudanças nas páginas vinculadas.

Comment: Estava escrevendo essa :) Considero essa tradução **urgente** porque ela é normalmente apresentada para orientar novatos que podem não saber inglês e em nome de um usuário (já confundi isso achando que o Sergio tinha escrito em inglês no site).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esta tradução foi internacionalizada. Pode ser que ainda haja um atraso na implementação até recebermos a tradução dos tradutores.

> This has been internationalized. There might be a slight delay in which we still use the English version while we receive the Portuguese version back from the translators.

Comment: Great! Thank you!